# Use .then() function on variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a variable that contains a function:

```js
let handler: () => Promise<string> = HTTP_REQUEST();
```

Why am I not able to call `.then()` on `handler`?

Example:

```js
handler.then(...)
```

Comment: .then needs to be called on the Promise<string> itself, your typedef indicates that you'd need to call it as `handler().then(...)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are on the right track. The variable contains a function. Do the following

```
handler().then(...)
```